For each $n \geq 3$ find an edge-to-edge monohedral tiling that has symmetry group $C_n$
I am currently solving exercises from The Tiling Book by Colin Adams. Rightnow, I am working on the exercises from Section 1.4.
The exercise involves constructing tilings of the Euclidean plane corresponding to specific symmetry groups. I was able to construct a tiling for the group $D_n$
For $D_n$, I constructed the following tiling,
n rhombus meeting at a vertex
However, I am struggling to construct a similar example for the cyclic group
My attempts so far:
My first thought was to modify the rhombuses from the $D_n$ case by curving their edges. However, the problem explicitly requires an edge-to-edge tiling, so the tiles need to be polygonal, not curved.
I then experimented with modifying the rhombus shape from the $D_n$ construction to make it asymmetric. See figures below:
Trying to preserve angles,
Trying to preverve side lengths,
Unfortunately, none of these modifications allowed the tiles to form a valid edge-to-edge tiling of the Euclidean plane.
I also tried several other polygonal shapes but encountered similar issues. Either the tiling wasn't edge-to-edge, or it didn't produce the required symmetry. (I tried Pentagons and hexagons as well)
Can anyone provide an example or construction of an edge-to-edge monohedral tiling of the Euclidean plane whose symmetry group is $C_n$
Any hints or suggestions for how to approach this problem would also be greatly appreciated

Your modifications change the location of a vertex. Try keeping the vertices at the same locations, and only changing the shape of the edges from a straight line to a "curved" one. You can change an edge to have a bump or dent like a jigsaw puzzle for example. You say they can't be actually curved, so just make them out of a series of straight lines, approximating the curved line you'd want.

The issue with adding dents is that they add new edges to the polygonal tiles. This leads to the tiling not being edge to edge.

It is still edge to edge. There is no edge of one tile that is adjacent to two or more edges of another tile (or equivalently, no vertex of one tile up against an edge of another tile).

The Tiling Book defines edge-to-edge tiling as: "In the case of a tiling by polygons such that the corners and sides of the polygons coincide with the vertices and edges of the tiling, we say the tiling is edge-to-edge."
The definition on Wiki is: "An edge-to-edge tiling is any polygonal tessellation where adjacent tiles only share one full side, i.e., no tile shares a partial side or more than one side with any other tile."
Is the meaning of side and corner different from the conventional meaning (side as the line segment bordering the polygon and corner as the meeting point of 2 sides)?

Sorry, I was wrong about the definition of edge to edge. You are correct that adjacent tiles in an edge-to-edge tiling share exactly one complete edge. Still, I don't see why such an edge needs to be a straight line and can't be curved.

In the book an edge to edge tiling is only defined for polygons, so I need straight lines and not curved
